# Determining Limits of Integration - Multiple Integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I was wondering whether someone could refresh my memory of something I think I remember learning when taking Calculus II or some similar class. Say, for example, that one has a function of a couple of variables, with respect to each of which one intends to integrate. Suppose there are also multiple conditions for the variables to satisfy. What method is used to convert the conditions into something that can be used to construct an integral?

In the event that this is not entirely clear, allow me to provide an example. Suppose one wishes to sum the function $f(x, y)$ with the conditions that $0 < x < 1$, $0 < y < 1$, and $x + y = 1$. If, for example, we solve this last condition for $y$, we find that $y = 1 - x$. Since the value of $(1 - x)$ is nonnegative for all $x \in \left(0, 1\right)$, can we simply integrate as
$$\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1-x}{f(x,y)} \hspace{5 px} dy} \hspace{5 px} dx?$$

Comment: No.  That would be the right integral if your condition were $y\le 1-x$ which I suspect is what you meant.  It you really want to integrate along the line $x+y=1$ you need a line integral, not a double integral.

Comment: So this would work if the conditions were $0 \leq x \leq 1$, $0 \leq y \leq 1$, $0 \leq y \leq 1-x$, since $(0 \leq x \leq 1) \cap (0 \leq y \leq 1 - x) \Rightarrow (y \leq 1)$?

Comment: @Wafflebaby Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi: That's great, but the answers received thus far only really answer the specific example, rather than what I am really interested in, which is a brief explanation of an overall method that works in different situations.

Comment: @Wafflebaby ok thanks, I’ll try to improve the answer!

Comment: @Wafflebaby Refer here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/MultipleIntegralsIntro.aspx for a general refresh on the subject and do not hesitate to ask for any clarification. Bye

Comment: Great. I think the stuff on integrating over general regions is what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1-x}{f(x,y)} \hspace{5 px} dy} \hspace{5 px} dx$$

corresponds to the [**triangular region**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Cy%3C1-x%20from%200%20to%201)

- $0\le x\le 1$
- $0\le y\le 1-x$

[image]

Comment: What would one have to do if one of the endpoints were not included in the area to be summed? That is, if the inequalities were strict.

Comment: It does not matter. Since the function does not have an infinite value at the endpoints, the contribution of the endpoints is $0$

Comment: @Wafflebaby It doesn't change the value of the integral

Comment: So for a more general method for arbitrary inequalities of multiple variables, one might have something like the following: express one variable's limits in terms of the others and set up an integral with respect to that variable; express the limits of another variable in terms of the other variables, not involving the first, and set up an integral, the integrand of which contains the previous integral; continue until there is a series of integrals with the condition that each expression that is in terms of variables that are being integrated are within the integrand of the respective integral

Answer (score 1):

The integral that you wrote has conditions $0\le x\le1$ and $0\le y\le 1-x$.

If you put the condition $x+y=1$, then the integral is one dimensional, and can be written as $\int_0^1f(x,1-x)dx$, or using delta functions

Comment: Would something similar hold true for integrals along other paths, such as given a condition $x^2 + y^2 = 1$?

Comment: Note that in this case I have $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$. If you choose only one of those paths, you are OK with just replacing it into the integral